# How can run skype in background?

Tags: daemon, skype

The latest way to install skype is with snap.

```
sudo snap install skype
```

Reboot,it can be started automatically and run in background daemon way.We can enable or disable its automatical startup in setting menu.It runs when automatical startup disabled:

```
sudo snap run skype
```

But the command can't be run in background as a normal daemon.

```
snap run skype  &
snap run skype  2>&1
```

Both of them can't make it run in background,how can run it in background then?

Comment: "_Both of them can't make it run in background_" - what happens that prevents you running the command with `&` as in your first example?

Comment: What about this command line: `nohup bash -c 'skype &'`

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make sense. skype isn't a server-level daemon and shouldn't be started at system start. What I *think* you want is a way for skype to be started when you log in to your desktop session, which is an entirely different beast and has an entirely different answer.

Comment: Showkey, if you want answers you need to respond to the questions here in the comments

Comment: "In the background" doesn't make sense in a graphical environment (and I've never heard anyone wanting to use skype outside one). As I'm typing this firefox has the focus, but thunderbird isn't technically in the background (i.e. it was just started - by my WM), it just doesn't have my attention. "In the background" is normally used when starting program from a terminal (emulator) and you don't want that program to block further usage of that terminal (emulator). I.e. I would use a `&` if I had to (re)start thunderbird from a terminal, but not from e.g. `rofi`.

Comment: If you had installed skype via `sudo snap install skype` in debian,how can you start it?There is no gui ,no menu to click,you can either write a service and `sudo systemctl start skype.service` or my way.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/755015/edit) to add information. Make it easy for people to help you by putting all the information usefully in a single place - don't add detail in the comments as it's all to easy to miss it

Comment: I have another issue "How to make mail command to send email to root after installing msmtp?" waiting for people to post answer,100 bonous is waiting still!

Comment: If you have another issue, ask another question!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@sudodus' the answer give me a hint:

```
nohup bash -c 'snap run skype &'
```

For the below commands:

```
snap run skype
snap run skype  &
snap run skype  2>&1
```

All of commands output many lines in terminal:

```
+ [ -f /home/debian/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/settings.json ]
+ export SKYPE_LOGS=/home/debian/snap/skype/293/logs
+ [ ! -d /home/debian/snap/skype/293/logs ]
+ exec /snap/skype/293/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux

(skypeforlinux:30941): dbind-WARNING **: 19:07:31.926: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-TGfeT7xGkl: No such file or directory
[30941:0830/190733.578850:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(271)] Gdk: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
[30941:0830/190737.051331:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method GetActive or interface org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.
```

`nohup bash -c 'snap run skype &'` can start skype and no output in the ternimal,that's i wanted.

Comment: Both your question and your self-answer are hardly understandable. I still don't understand what did you actually want to achieve, what was the problem (what went wrong) and how exactly did the posted command solve the problem.